# Python decorator module - kwargs

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Using the decorator module from Michele Simionato, I'm getting a weird behavior with respect to kwargs. Here's an example using the simple example that is [in the documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/decorator/documentation.html):

```
def _trace(f, *args, **kw):
    kwstr = ', '.join('%r: %r' % (k, kw[k]) for k in sorted(kw))
    print("calling %s with args %s, {%s}" % (f.__name__, args, kwstr))
    return f(*args, **kw)

def trace(f):
    return decorate(f, _trace)

@trace
def f(a, b, c=1, d=1):
    return a + b + c + d

f(1,2,c=2,d=2)
```

prints `calling f with args (1, 2, 3, 4), {}`

instead of `calling f with args (1, 2), {'c': 2, 'd': 2}`

Is it wanted behavior? Why so?

Or did I get something wrong?

Comment: The wrapped function works perfectly well either way, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the expected behavior. From the [page you linked](http://pythonhosted.org/decorator/documentation.html#id10):

```
>>> @trace
... def f(x, y=1, z=2, *args, **kw):
...     pass

>>> f(0, 3)
calling f with args (0, 3, 2), {}

>>> print(getargspec(f))
ArgSpec(args=['x', 'y', 'z'], varargs='args', varkw='kw', defaults=(1, 2))
```

Notice how the `y` and `z` keyword arguments show up as regular args, not keyword args.

Comment: The `y=1` and `z=2` values are just default argument values, though, not keyword arguments. Whether an argument has a default value is entirely independent of whether it's passed positionally or by keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Expectation is not correct with current prototype of f(a, b, c=1, d=1), It is just default argument type. Change f to accept keyargs-

```
@trace
def f(a, b, **kargs):
    return a + b + kargs['c'] + kargs['d'] 
f(1,2,c=2,d=2)
calling f with args (1, 2), {'c': 2, 'd': 2}
```